# What is the nearest Version available to SLES 10.2 SP3 ,

Tags: linux, enterprise, suse

I am looking for SLES 10.2 SP3 OS installer image but could not find it anywhere . is it available anywhere, if not  what is the next nearest available version available.

Comment: anybody has any info on this topic ?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what `SLES 10.2 SP3` is supposed to mean. There is no equivalent of SUSE Linux for SLES10 (unlike newer SLE variants, which are used as a base for Leap).

The closest is likely SUSE Linux 10.2 or SUSE Linux 10.3. Maybe there is still copy on `ftp.gwdg.de`.

See release dates of SLES10: https://www.suse.com/lifecycle

Compare this with release dates of SUSE Linux: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux

Comment: What I meant with SLES is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server , we need 10.2 SP3 , but could not find it available anywhere.

Comment: Well, there is no such thing as "SLES 10.2 SP3", it is either `SLES10 SP2` or `SLES10 SP3`, see the "lifecycle" URL above.
But apart from this unimportant detail, it will most likely be difficult, or truly impossible, to obtain a copy after such a long time, if it really must be exactly a variant of SLES10.